# Disabling a Button in IE6, IE7, IE8?

Tags: jquery, html, button

I am trying to disable a button - using jQuery 1.4.4 the following code in IE

`jQuery('#id').attr("disabled", true);`

With the HTML of

```
<button id="id" type="button"
    class="some-class"
     disabled="">Comment</button>
```

Works in FF, Chrome etc and of course, doesn't work in IE ? How can I fix ?

i.e. the `<button disabled="disabled">` doesn't seem to work in IE or ?

**Edit:** Note also that `<button id='id' disabled>foobar</button>` is valid html

Comment: @WTP :) - IE just loves *pi#$&ng* off your day

Comment: @Tom: I know how you feel. If you see Redmond on fire in the news, give me a call - I'll go and chuck some petrol on it.

Comment: @JamWaffles I'll buy you the petrol, it's expensive these days.

Comment: @WTP Actually, this is a bug in Chrome/FF. *IE* is strictly following the spec here.

Comment: @WTP: Thanks :-D it will go to a good cause, so you can live with a free conscience.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

XML/HTML attribute values are strings. The values "true" and "false" [have no special meaning (technically, they aren't even *allowed*)](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#boolean-attributes). The convention is to set the value to the attribute name:

```
jQuery('#id').attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

Also note that in your HTML, `<button disabled="">` will already disable the button. Just leave out the `disabled` attribute or re-enable it with jQuery:

```
jQuery('#id').removeAttr("disabled");
```

Comment: Sorry, but this isn't right. When you are trying to check a checkbox in JQuery the only way it will work is with $("input[type=checkbox]").attr("checked",true);

Comment: @philhag - is it just me or does `<button id='id' disabled=''>foobar</button>` actually disable the button in IE ? http://jsfiddle.net/kxVRx/9/

Comment: @Liam Baily The behavior is fixed in the HTML5 standard, so I'm not certain how it couldn't be right. Anyway, `$("input[type=checkbox]").attr("checked","checked");` [*does* work](http://phihag.de/2011/so/jquery-checked.html).

Comment: @Tom No, it's not you. This is the correct behavior. An enabled button  has no attribute `disabled`. Updated the answer to reflect that.

Comment: @philhag - so you can actually use [directly via html] `<button id='id' disabled>foobar</button>` or is this invalid ?

Comment: @Tom This is perfectly valid and disables your button right from the start. If you wish, you can write `disabled="disabled"` to make that clear (and allow your page to be valid XML).

Comment: @philhag - legend! thanks for brightening up my day and allowing me to move back into the world of Chrome and FF and away from evil evil IE :)

Answer (score 1):

I was having identical issues in IE8, and was able to solve them, so thought I'd add-in a couple points. The solution offered by phihag is both right and wrong. It's true that XML/HTML won't accept a true boolean value as an attribute--but we're talking about jQuery syntax, here, which does accept booleans as arguments, and sets attributes appropriately.

With the disabling and enabling of input elements, in IE, what I found to work, consistently, is to simply *not* "hard-code" the initial desired value directly in the X/HTML. If a control is to be disabled from the initial render, it's best to call a function as soon as the page is rendered, to disable it. Perhaps a bit of a kludge and, like many things, it ought not be that way, but that's what's ended-up working for me. Very simple.

Hope that helps someone. I went through a lot of debugging efforts to pinpoint that one.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 jQuery('#id').attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

Attribute values should be strings, not boolean

Comment: He wants to disable, not enable the button

Comment: @alex - i want to disable the button in IE - the problem is that IE doesn't seem to like the above code ? i.e. a user can just click and it doesn't disable the button ?

Comment: D'oh again. I keep doing that today. Edited

Answer (score 0):

Just to add some extra value to the other answers posted here.

I think your wording is a bit off and by the looks of it, you want to know how to both disable and re-enable a button cross browser.

The `disabled` attribute, when present, should always disable the element, no matter what it's value is. The recommended value is `disabled="disabled"`.

```
$('#id').attr("disabled", "disabled")
```

In order to re-enable the element you'll want to remove the `disabled` attrbitute altogether (as pointed out in other answers).

```
$('#id').removeAttr('disabled');
```

Answer (score 0):

This is from [JQuery API documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/button/#option-disabled):

```
$( ".selector" ).button( "option", "disabled", true );
```

It works for me even in IE 8 with JQuery UI 1.8.14 or higher. In older versions the click events are fired even on disabled buttons. So in the event, you have to evaluate disabledness of the button and cancel the event:

```
function clickHandler(event) {
    if ($(event.currentTarget).button("option", "disabled")) {
        return false;
    }
    // other handle stuff...
}
```